# Rotation animation slows down my WPF interface

Tags: wpf, animation

I have a button with a style.

That style has an image:

```
<ContentPresenter.Content>
<Grid>
.
.
.
<Image x:Name="RecordingImage"
           Source="/Studio;component/Images/Icons/image.png"
           Width="107"
           Height="107"
           RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5"
           Visibility="Hidden">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
```

And is animated with this code:

```
<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
<Setter TargetName="RecordingImage" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
<Trigger.EnterActions>
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation 
                Storyboard.TargetName="RecordingImage" 
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)" 
                From="0" To="360" Duration="00:00:03.000" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</Trigger.EnterActions>
```

But when the animation begins, all my interface slows down.

What is the problem?

Comment: Maybe the image is very large? (notice that the width and height you write in the XAML has nothing to do with performance, only display).

Comment: @MaMazav, the image is of 107 x 107 and his size is 1001 bytes...

Comment: Hmm. What another graphics is displayed? maybe heavy graphics which is partially hidden by the image and need to be rerendered when the image moves?

Comment: Well, i have various cameras at different sizes using wpfmediakit. 
Although none of them is behind the button with animation. 
I have aslo performance problems with wpfmediakit, but when the animation starts they are much more evidents.

Comment: If the other graphics is really the source of the problem, you can try to isolate the rendering of the animated scene and the other graphics to avoid render all the scene when having it animated. For example, you can put the animated scene within an ElementHost which will be within WinFormsHost, but I guess there are other non-hacky ways to isolate the rendering. Hope it helps.